# How to detect a MPI_Request object is enabled by MPI_Isend or MPI_Send_init?

Tags: mpi

There are two ways that we can enable a `MPI_Request` object `request`.

The first way is using `MPI_Isend`. In this way, the requset should NOT freed by `MPI_Request_free` after finished.

The second way is using `MPI_Send_init`, and in this way, the requset should by freed by `MPI_Request_free` after finished.

I want to 'free' the resource after using MPI_Request object.If it is enabled by `MPI_Send_init`, I should call `MPI_Request_free`. If it is enabled by `MPI_Isend`, call the `MPI_Request_free` will leads to error.

How to detect a MPI_Request object `request`enabled by `MPI_Isend` or `MPI_Send_init`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: there is no such subroutine in the MPI standard. the rationale for `MPI_Send_init()` is that the buffer content will be send more than once (e.g. `MPI_Start()` will be called more than once) so this is quite different compared to `MPI_Isend()`. IMHO, your question suggests you are mixing persistent and non persistent point to point requests, and you should consider revamping your program not to do that (for example, did you consider you might free an active persistent request before cancelling it?)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks. I would take your advise and modify my code, separate manage the request for persistent and non persistent communication.